# Show element by clicking/hovering on different element

Tags: user-interface, components, autolayout, user-experience, figma

Fairly new to Figma and I kindof understand how components work. But what I'm trying to do is change element 1 from variant 1 to 2 (visibility on/off) based on hovering on element 2.

More specifically, the scenario I'm trying to implement is this:

- Two columns. Column 1 has several content blocks stacked over each other (negative auto layout spacing). All of these stay disabled/visibility off by default.
- Column 2 has several ellipses/nodes
- Requirement: If I hover/click node 1, content 1 is visible. If I hover/click node 2, content 1 hides and content 2 is visible.

Other methods of implementation are also appreciated if mine is too convoluted.